# ASP.NET AJAX really slow after upgrading to IIS 7.5 ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, iis-7.5, updatepanel, asp.net-4.5

I have several legacy applications built originally on asp.net 2.0, IIS 6 and update panels. They were working fine on that old server, response time was never more than 4 seconds.

I moved them to a new windows 2008 server with IIS 7.5 and performance is much slower at 20 seconds per async request/response.

- The code has not changed
- Database has not changed.
- The appPool is running in classic mode.
- The database responds immediately once it receives the query (again
  it takes 20 seconds for the database to receive the query)
- I have installed the latest AJAXControlToolkit for ASP.net 4.5.

I did some analysis and found that the request is what is taking so long but I don't know why. I have tried switching to integrated mode but that had no positive effect.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks, Justin.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the value of <httpRuntime executionTimeout>?

Comment: I do not have that set.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a network issue to me.

> Database has not changed.

Database has not changed and you've moved the code to a new server. Are you accessing the DB through a local IP? If not, you need to do that. 
Verify the connection speed by pinging the old DB server from your new server and see if it is taking a long time to get a reply.

> The database responds immediately once it receives the query (again it takes 20 seconds for the database to receive the query)

If the database is quick in responding and it was working fine earlier, there is no chance that there is any problem with it. Something is fishy in data transmission over the network.

**Just in case, it is not a network problem:**

1) Please clean and rebuild the solution and upload it again. Deleting all the "bin" folders in every project and rebuilding them again worked for me. It was the reason behind my problem.

2) Please make sure that you are using the latest builds of DB connectors just in case you are using [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) or [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

3) You may want to use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to trace your http requests and see where exactly the problem is.